# css problem in chrome and not in IE

Tags: css, templates, joomla, cross-browser

I have a strange problem with css with a joomla template and I don't understand how to solve it.

try to view this site in firefox or IE (xD) and then in chrome.

http://edited

you will see that the red bar in chrome not correct...how can I fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ja-current-content{
  clear: both;
}
```